# How do I nest the Cell "Address" Formula into a VLookup? in Excel

Tags: excel, cell, vlookup

So here are the Columns:

```
Column A: Date
Column B: Prices of NASDAQ
Column C: Prices of ABC Stocks
```

I want to run a financial beta formula, `(=COVAR(C1:C1000,B1:B1000)/VAR(B1:B1000)`.
But, I don't want the cells to always start from the first row... I want to be able to calculate this formula at different rows.

For example, if I have `(=COVAR(C60:C1000,B60:B1000)/VAR(B60:B1000)`
I want to be able to make that change by referring to a date in a new cell labeled "Start Date" without rewriting each formula.

I'm thinking of nesting a `=Cell("address")` formula within a vlookup, but I'm having trouble with this.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX` is usually preferable to `INDIRECT` for 2 reasons

1.) `INDIRECT` is a "volatile" function which means that it re-calculates every time the worksheet changes - potentially slowing everything down

2.) With `INDEX` you don't need to "hardcode" the column letters like "C" so the formula will still work if you add or delete columns.

It would look like this

`=COVAR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(Date,A:A,0)):C1000,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(Date,A:A,0)):B1000)/VAR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(Date,A:A,0)):B1000)`

...or rather than repeating the same `MATCH` function 3 times you could put the `MATCH` part alone in a separate cell or make it a named range - e.g. named **start** and formula becomes:

`=COVAR(INDEX(C:C,start):C1000,INDEX(B:B,start):B1000)/VAR(INDEX(B:B,start):B1000)`